# Extension of PDE's to critical strip

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, analytic-number-theory, harmonic-analysis, riemann-zeta

**Introduction:**

In statistics, distributions in the exponential family are very natural to consider. One famous example is the Gaussian. It shows up in the heat equation, in probability theory, and in many other fields. While the Gaussian may be most important due to the central limit theorem, distributions in the exponential family have properties that may be connected to the properties of the Gaussian itself.  So, consider the exponential family, the close cousin of the Gaussian, $f_s(x)=e^{sT(x)}$ for parameter $s$ and sufficient statistic $T(x)=\frac{1}{\log x}.$

**Relating $f_s(x)$ to the Riemann zeta function:**

Viewing $f_s(x)$ geometrically:

The function $f_s(x)$ is a particular solution to a linear parabolic diffusion equation (use an exponential ansatz):

$$s \frac{\partial ^2f(s,x)}{\partial s^2}=-x \frac{\partial f(s,x)}{\partial x} \tag{2}$$

and the Mellin transform can be used to transform that equation to (transform the solution $f_s(x)$ and use a CAS to verify):

$$r^2 \frac{\partial ^3\Psi(r,s)}{\partial r^3}=s^2 \frac{\partial \Psi(r,s)}{\partial s} \tag{3}$$

where a particular solution Bessel function, $K_1$ appears:

$$\Psi(r,s)=2 \sqrt{\frac{r}{s}}K_1(2\sqrt{r s})$$

We recover a connection with the Riemann zeta function and the Gamma function:

$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(w-1)\Gamma(w)}\int_0^\infty \sum_{r \in \Bbb N} \Psi(r,s) s^{w-1}~ds=\zeta(w-1) \tag{1}$$

convergent for $\Re(w)>2.$

We can recover the symmetric functional equation about the critical strip $\xi(s)=\xi(1-s)$ through this integral relationship and analytic continuation, although it is calculation intensive.

**A more fundamental approach:**

Another, perhaps more fundamental, way to obtain the symmetric functional equation is to start with any Schwartz function. Usually the self dual Gaussian is used to obtain the Gamma factor $\Gamma(s/2)\pi^{-s/2}.$ Here I ask for a closed form for the Gamma factor associated to the Schwartz class $f_s(x):$

[Obtaining the correct Gamma factor for this Schwartz function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4754147/460999).

We are looking for a functional equation of this form:

$$\Gamma(f,r,s)\cdot \zeta(s) \;=\; \Gamma(\hat{f},r,1-s)\cdot \zeta(1-s)\tag{4}$$

Here, $\Gamma$ is the Gamma factor and $\hat f$ denotes the Fourier transform. Note however, that the fundamental domain of $f$ is $(0,1)$ so the Fourier transform will act on this bounded domain.

Here I will show the calculation of $\Gamma(f,r,s):$

$$\Gamma(f,r,s)=\int_{\mathbb R^\times \cap ~(0,1)} |x|^r~f_s(x)~{dx\over |x|}=2 \sqrt{\frac{r}{s}}K_1(2\sqrt{r s})$$

for modified Bessel function of the second kind $K_1.$

**Informal discussion and remarks:**

In terms of geometric analysis $\Psi(r,s)$ has an interpretation as a $1$-parameter family of Riemannian metrics which can be shown using the Fisher methodology and information geometry, and this is how I initially started thinking about $\Psi(r,s)$. I initially thought of it as a Fisher metric.

With this linear geometric flow we have essentially summed discrete pieces of the metric, over a spectrum, in this case the natural numbers, and then taken the Mellin transform to recover the zeta function.

That is to say, $f_s(x)$ seems to be "weakly" tied to the Riemann zeta function. If you start with $f_s(x)$ and *pretend* that you can take two Mellin transforms in a row and sum over the natural numbers you recover the Riemann zeta i.e. formula $(1).$ Of course it doesn't make sense to take iterative Mellin transforms like this. But already, you can see that $f_s(x)$ is deeply linked to $\zeta(s)$. And this really isn't that surprising, given the modern viewpoint of things as in Iwasawa-Tate theory.

Now I claimed above, that $f_s(x)$ was Schwartz $\forall s >0.$ You may be very skeptical about this and rightfully so. This is a delicate situation and I'll explain why. The Schwartz space is classically defined for functions on the *real* line and so there must be some functional analysis work done to show that $f_s(x)$ can legitimately be thought of as a kind of Schwartz function. I believe things will work out just fine, under the appropriate modifications, but I personally do not know enough functional analysis to tie everything up neatly here.

**Question:**

At this point I'd like to state my question. As the title says I am looking to extend the two PDE's $(2)$ and $(3)$ to the critical strip as defined through $(4).$

> How do you extend $(2)$ and $(3)$ to the critical strip as defined by $(4)?$

**Explorations of the literature:**

Here are some other attempts of mine to educate myself on the approaches that have already been developed. Most relevant I think is the de Bruijn constant:

I've read Tao's article about freezing and vaporizing the Riemann zeta function. Also see [de Bruijn constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn%E2%80%93Newman_constant). Here is Tao's presentation:

https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2018/08/webinar.pdf.

This seems related since $f_s(x)$ obeys a strange kind of "backwards heat equation"  $$s \frac{\partial ^2f(s,x)}{\partial s^2}=-x \frac{\partial f(s,x)}{\partial x}$$

I do know that the Mellin transform by definition maps some function $\psi : (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{C}$ with $\mathcal{M}(\psi)(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \psi(x) x^s  \frac{dx}{x}$

that's absolutely convergent on the vertical strip $\lbrace s \in \mathbb{C} : a < \Re(s) < b \rbrace$.

So it seems to me that this sum of the metric over a particular spectrum of the naturals, is being converted from a real $s$ to a complex $w$ through the Mellin transform. So, I guess that's where I'm stuck. I don't know how to connect that complex object to the $1$-parameter family of real metrics.

It seems closely related to this too: https://mathoverflow.net/q/139863/123449, but I don't know if the argument applies since the operator of my PDE is not a second order p.d.o. (it's third order) among other things. I mean I guess it could be reduced to second order through a Fourier transform but I don't know how to proceed exactly.

**Final remarks:**

$(A).~f_s(x)$ is a $1$-parameter class, and therefore we should have a varying, or $1$-parameter class of functional equations.

$(B).~$The Gamma factor is also a $1$-parameter class.

$(C).~$I think there is a way to unify $(A)$ and $(B)$ on the critical strip, using existing mathematical methods.

$(D).~$Any argument showing that $f_s(x)$ cannot be used to obtain $(4)$ would also answer this question, essentially providing a counterexample.

Comment: Can you please provide a reference for the Mellin transform of the diffusion equation?

Comment: I don't know if it helps but$$\xi(s)=s\, \mathcal{M}_x[f(x)](-s)=s \int\limits_0^\infty f(x)\, x^{-s-1}\, dx=\pi^{-\frac{s}{2}}\, (s-1)\, \Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}+1\right) \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s},\quad\Re(s)>1$$ where $$f(x)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{2 \pi  n^2}{x^2}-1\right) e^{-\frac{\pi  n^2}{x^2}}.$$ The function $f(x)$ is an even function of $x$, but seems to resemble a cumulative distribution function (CDF) when scaled by a factor of $2$ and plotted in the right-half plane.

Comment: @JamesArathoon Unfortunately I don't have a reference - but the PDE (3) is found by taking the Mellin transform of $f_s(x)$ on the support of $f.$ And you pose a good question because it's a bit unclear how to arrive rigorously at $(3).$ For me it was a recognition game because I knew $f_s(x)$ under Mellin should satisfy a new PDE

Comment: @JamesArathoon I think there is nothing mysterious going on because if you Wick transform (2) you get essentially the same PDE as if you Fourier transform (3). This is well known.

Comment: @StevenClark I'm not sure what you're trying to do there

Comment: You mentioned statistics, distributions, Mellin transforms, and the Riemann Xi function, and I suspect $f(x)$ (when scaled by a factor of $2$ and evaluated for $x>0$) qualifies as a cumulative distribution function (CDF) which is related to the Riemann Xi function $\xi(s)$ via the Mellin transform I defined in my previous comment.

Comment: @StevenClark Okay. $f_s(x)$ maps a different Gamma factor onto the functional equation - the Gamma factor is Bessel related I don't know the exact form of the factor because I can't find the closed form of the Fourier transform of $f$ but it's not a Gamma function anymore. Now, the Schwartz class is dynamic because it obeys (2). This means the functional equation is dynamic. The Mellin transform of the Schwartz class is dynamic as well.

Comment: Point being - these dynamics extend to the critical strip.

Comment: I don't believe your Mellin transform is correct. I believe the result is actually $\zeta(w-1)$ which is valid for $\Re(w)>2$. Also for $$g(x)=\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty} \psi(r,x)$$ one has $$\frac{1}{\Gamma(s) \Gamma(s+1)} \mathcal{M}_x[g(x)](s+1)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s) \Gamma(s+1)} \int\limits_0^{\infty} g(x)\, x^s \, dx=\zeta(s)\,,\quad\Re(s)>1$$.

Comment: The Mellin transform of $g(x)$ of course gives $\zeta(s)$ (you are right to conclude that) but the reason I chose specifically not to use $g(x)$ is because it doesn't satisfy a non-trivial differential equation. I chose to use the $\Psi(r,x)$ (in my post) because it does satisfy a non-trivial PDE.

Comment: @StevenClark And like I said in the post there are 2 ways to find the symmetric functional equation. One is starting with the Schwartz class $f_s(x)$ and the other is found by taking the Mellin transform of the sum of my $\Psi(r,x)$ over $r$. The former method is the more fundamental.

Comment: @StevenClark It's more fundamental for a few reasons but one of which is because it allows you to trade the Gamma factor for a Bessel function instead of a Gamma function and that new factor satisfies a linear third order pde. The Gamma function when used as a Gamma factor does not satisfy an algebraic D.E. by holder's theorem.  The Bessel function here does satisfy an algebraic D.E.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying about me being wrong. For $$\Psi(r,s)=2 \sqrt{\frac{r}{s}}\, K_1\left(2 \sqrt{r s}\right)$$ defined in your question above, the Mellin transform $$\frac{1}{\Gamma(w-1)\, \Gamma(w)}\, \mathcal{M}_s\left[\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty} \Psi(r,s)\right](w)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(w-1)\, \Gamma (w)} \int_0^{\infty } \left(\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty} \Psi(r,s)\right)  s^{w-1}\, ds$$ defined in formula (1) of your question above evaluates to $\zeta(w-1)$.

Comment: Note that $$\frac{1}{\Gamma(w-1)\, \Gamma(w)} \mathcal{M}_s[\Psi(r,s)](w)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(w-1)\, \Gamma(w)} \int_0^{\infty} \Psi (r,s)\, s^{w-1} \, ds=r^{1-w}$$ and $\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty} r^{1-w}=\zeta(w-1)$ for $\Re(w)>2$.

Comment: $\zeta(w)=\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{r^w}$ for $\Re(w)>1$, so $\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty} r^{1-w}=\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{r^{w-1}}=\zeta(w-1)$ for $\Re(w)>2$.

Comment: @StevenClark Oh okay I gotcha now. Good catch. I'll update the body of the post with your correction.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. For $f_s(x)=e^{\frac{r}{\log(x)}}$ and $\Psi(r,s)=2 \sqrt{\frac{r}{s}}\, K_1\left(2 \sqrt{r s}\right)$, I believe one has $$\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}[\Psi(r,s)](x)=f_s(x)\,,\quad 0<x<1,$$ and therefore $$\mathcal{M}_x\left[(\theta(x)-\theta(x-1))\, f_s(x)\right](s)=\int\limits_0^1 f_s(x)\, x^{s-1}\, dx=\Psi(r,s)$$ where $f_s(x)$ satisfies formula (1) and $\Psi (r,s)$ satisfies formula (2).

Comment: But you're taking then taking a second Mellin transform $\frac{1}{\Gamma(w-1)\, \Gamma(w)}\, \mathcal{M}_s\left[\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty} \Psi(r,s)\right](w)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(w-1)\, \Gamma (w)} \int_0^{\infty } \left(\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty} \Psi(r,s)\right)  s^{w-1}\, ds=\zeta(w-1)$ which is valid for $\Re(s)>2$. How do formulas (2) and (3) relate to the analytic continuation of $\zeta(w-1)$ derived from this second Mellin transform and the non-trivial zeros in the critical strip?

Comment: @StevenClark That's exactly my question: "Can we use (2) and (3)
 to analyze the "flow" of the non-trivial zeros on the critical strip?" I'm asking how these PDE's extend to the critical strip compatible with the symmetric functional equation. An explanation of that is what I'm after.

Comment: Formula (2) is transformed to formula (3) by the first Mellin transform. Is formula (3) transformed to another PDE by the second Mellin transform?

Comment: @StevenClark no but as I said, fourier transform of (3) is essentially equivalent to Wick transform of (2)

Comment: In formula (4) is the dot operator multiplication? If so, wouldn't this imply $\Gamma(\hat{f},r,1-s)=\Gamma(f,r,s)\,\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(1-s)}=\Gamma(f,r,s)\, 2^s \pi ^{s-1} \sin \left(\frac{\pi  s}{2}\right) \Gamma (1-s)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the function

$$g_r(x)=r^2 \frac{\partial^3\Psi(r,x)}{\partial r^3}=x^2 \frac{\partial \Psi(r,x)}{\partial x}=-2 r \sqrt{\frac{1}{x}} x^{3/2} K_2\left(2 \sqrt{r x}\right),\quad r>0\tag{1}$$

is only Schwartz in the right-half plane, so consider the even function $h_r(x)=g_r(|x|)$ instead for which

$$\Gamma\left[h_r,s\right]=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty h_r(x)\, |x|^{s-1}\, dx=2 \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty h_r(x)\, x^{s-1}\, dx$$ $$=-2\, r^{-s}\, \Gamma(s)\, \Gamma(s+2),\quad r>0\land\Re(s)>0\tag{2}$$

and

$$\Gamma\left[\hat{h_r},1-s\right]=\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(1-s)}\, \Gamma\left[h_r,s\right]=2^s\, \pi^{s-1}\, \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\, \Gamma(1-s)\, \Gamma\left[h_r,s\right]$$ $$=-(2 \pi)^s \left(\frac{1}{r}\right)^s \sec\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right) \Gamma(s+2)\tag{3}$$

where $\hat{h_r}(w)=\mathcal{F}_x[h_r(x)](w)$ is the Fourier transform of $h_r(x)$.

---

The Fourier transform of $h_r(x)$ is

$$\hat{h_r}(w)=\mathcal{F}_x[h_r(x)](w)=\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty} h_r(x)\, e^{-i 2 \pi w x} \, dx=\frac{i r e^{-\frac{i r}{2 \pi w}}}{8 \pi^3 w^3} \left(4 i \pi w e^{\frac{i r}{2 \pi w}}+r e^{\frac{i r}{\pi  w}}\, \Gamma\left(0,\frac{i r}{2 \pi w}\right)-r\, \Gamma\left(0,-\frac{i r}{2 \pi w}\right)\right),\quad r>0\tag{4}$$

and $\Gamma\left[\hat{h_r},1-s\right]$ evaluated using formula (4) for $\hat{h_r}(w)$ above is

$$\Gamma\left[\hat{h_r},1-s\right]=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{h_r}(w)\, |w|^{s-1}\, dw=2 \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{h_r}(w)\, w^{s-1}\, dw=\frac{i r}{4 \pi^3} \left(8 i \pi^2 \delta(-i (s+1))+\frac{2^{s+2} \pi^{s+3} \left(\left(\frac{i}{r}\right)^s-\left(-\frac{i}{r}\right)^s\right) \csc(\pi s) \Gamma(s+2)}{r}\right)\tag{5}$$

which is equivalent to formula (3) for $\Gamma\left[\hat{h_r},1-s\right]$ above when ignoring the $8 i \pi^2 \delta(-i (s+1))$ term in formula (5) above (which corresponds to a pole of $\Gamma\left[\hat{h_r},1-s\right]$ at $s=-1$).

---

I believe the function

$$u_r(x)=r \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial r^2}e^{\frac{r}{\log (x)}}=-x \frac{\partial }{\partial x}e^{\frac{r}{\log (x)}}=\frac{r\, e^{\frac{r}{\log (x)}}}{\log ^2(x)}\tag{6}$$

may perhaps be a Schwartz function for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, but instead consider the simpler even function $v_r(x)=u(|x|)$ over the interval $x\in(-1,1)$ for which

$$\Gamma\left[v_r,s\right]=\int\limits_{-1}^1 v_r(x)\, |x|^{s-1}\, dx=2 \int\limits_{-1}^1 v_r(x)\, x^{s-1}\, dx$$ $$=4 \sqrt{r s}\, K_1\left(2 \sqrt{r s}\right),\quad r>0\land\Re(s)>0\tag{7}$$

and

$$\Gamma\left[\hat{v_r},1-s\right]=\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(1-s)}\, \Gamma\left[v_r,s\right]=2^s\, \pi^{s-1}\, \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\, \Gamma(1-s)\, \Gamma\left[v_r,s\right]\tag{8}$$

where $\hat{v_r}(w)=\mathcal{F}_x[v_r(x)](w)$ is the Fourier transform of $v_r(x)$.

---

I don't have a closed form for $\hat{v_r}(w)$ but $v_1(x)$, $\hat{v_1}(w)$ and $\Gamma\left[\hat{v_1},1-s\right]$ can all be approximated by series representations analogous to formulas (4), (7), and (9) of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4757232) to a related question where in this case the Fourier coefficients

$$a_k=\int\limits_{-1}^1 v_1(x)\, \cos(\pi k x)\, dx\tag{9}$$

can again be approximated via numeric integration.

---

Figure (1) below illustrates the series representation of $\Gamma\left[\hat{v_1},1-s\right]$ in orange overlaid on the closed form for $\Gamma\left[\hat{v_1},1-s\right]$ defined in formula (8) above in blue.

[image: Illustration of the series representation of \hat{v_1}(w) (orange) overlaid on formula (8) for \Gamma\left[\hat{v_1},1-s\right]]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of the series representation of $\Gamma\left[\hat{v_1},1-s\right]$ (orange) overlaid on formula (8) for $\Gamma\left[\hat{v_1},1-s\right]$ (blue)

---

Comment: Does this answer the question ?

Comment: Question is: How do you extend $(2)$ and $(3)$ (as pertaining to my post) to the critical strip?

Comment: This is great...but I would have expected at least a remark about whether the Schwartz satisfying $(2)$ carries any information onto the critical strip

Comment: @geocalc33 Carries any information about what? The Dirichlet series for the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}$ is only valid for $\Re(s)>1$, and the Riemann zeta functional equation $\zeta(s)=\pi^{s-1}\, \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\, \Gamma(1-s)\, \zeta(1-s)$ is only valid for $\Re(s)<0$ when the $\zeta(1-s)$ term on the right-hand side is evaluated as $\zeta(1-s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1-s}}$.

Comment: @geocalc33 The Riemann zeta functional equation is valid in the critical strip only when using an analytic continuation of $\zeta(s)$ that converges in the critical strip, and the plots in my [related answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4757232) used the Mathematica function $\text{Zeta[s]}$ which is the analytic continuation of the Dirichlet series for $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: @geocalc33 My answer is based on my interpretation of what you meant by "How do you extend (2) and (3) to the critical strip as defined by (4)?". I derived the function equations in your (4) using the definitions in your (2) and (3). Please clarify if you were asking for something else.

Comment: @geocalc33 I believe the Schwartz functions satisfying your (2) and (3) can be used to derive the Riemann zeta functional equation, but I don't see how they provide any information on the location of the non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ other than $\zeta(s)=0$ implies $\zeta(1-s)=0$ in the critical strip which is a result of the functional equation.

Comment: Okay fair enough - (+1). I will have to think about how this relates to the PDE's another time

Comment: I won't be awarding this answer the bounty. It's perhaps accurate but not super clear, and I don't like the use of, 'I believe,' twice for your central arguments.

Comment: @Integrand I added information to my answer placing it on more solid ground, but I'm not really worried about the bounty.

Comment: @StevenClark just FYI; it’s a habit I have with bounties to explain one way or another.

Comment: @JohnZimmerman Note formula (7) in my answer above is related to your question on [Verification of integral representation of zeta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4653725). The relationship $$\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[2\, \sqrt{r s}\, K_1\left(2\, \sqrt{r s}\right)\right](x)=r\, \frac{e^{\frac{r}{\log(x)}}}{\log^2(x)}\,\quad 0<x<1$$ is analogous to the relationship $$\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[2\, \sqrt{\frac{r}{s}}\, K_1\left(2\, \sqrt{r s}\right)\right](x)=e^{\frac{r}{\log(x)}}\,,\quad 0<x<1.$$

Comment: @StevenClark thanks!