# Obtaining the correct Gamma factor for this Schwartz function

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis, schwartz-space

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4752960/460999) I overlooked that the class $f_s(x)=e^{sT(x)}$ for $T(x)=\frac{1}{\log x},$ is [Schwartz](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchwartzFunction.html), on $x \in (0,1).$ Therefore we can obtain a functional equation, see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/180548/123449).

However, I am having some difficulties obtaining the Gamma factor. I started by writing down the calculation:

$$\Gamma(f,r,s)=\int_{\mathbb R^\times \cap ~(0,1)} |x|^r~f_s(x)~{dx\over |x|}=2 \sqrt{\frac{r}{s}}K_1(2\sqrt{r s})$$

Where $K_1$ is a modified Bessel. But something isn't right. It would seem that I have to find the Fourier transform of $f_s(x).$ However, I'm not sure how to get a closed form for that.

> How do you get the correct Gamma factor for the class of Schwartz functions $f_s(x)?$

This Schwartz function is its own inverse i.e. satisfies $f\circ f=\mathrm{id}$ but I'm not sure if that can help here.

Edit: Someone pointed me in the direction of Pontryagin duality. They said to view $(0,1)$ as the torus $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ with group operation as addition modulo $1$. And they said that roughly speaking, the Fourier transform of a function on $(0,1)$ is a Fourier series.

I am currently following this lead and hopefully it will resolve this question.

Comment: Does $f\circ f$ refer to the Fourier convolution $\int\limits_0^y e^{\frac{1}{\log(x)}} e^{\frac{1}{\log(y-x)}} \, dx$? The identity with respect to Fourier convolution is the Dirac delta function $\delta(x)$, but I don't think that's what you mean here. What is the definition of $\mathrm{id}$?

Comment: @StevenClark $f \circ f$ is the composition of $f$ with itself yielding the identity function

Comment: @StevenClark I simply mean that the inverse of $f$ is itself. It's an involution.

Comment: In other words we have an endomorphism on the class $f_s(x)$ for all $s.$ I wrote this down because this endomorphism provides a symmetry for the "Schwartz" function. I sense that exploiting this symmetry could be useful and analogous to exploiting the symmetry of "even" and "self-dual" Schwartz functions like the Gaussian function which is both even and self dual, allowing for a relatively simple Gamma factor.

Comment: Assuming $f_s(x)=e^\frac{s}{\log(x)}$, is it true that $f_s(f_s(z))=z$ for every $s\in\mathbb{C}\land s\ne0$ and for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @StevenClark I do not know

Comment: Note it simplifies to $f_s(f_s(z))=e^\frac{s}{\log(e^\frac{s}{\log(z)})}=e^\frac{s}{\frac{s}{\log(z)}}=e^{\log(z)}=z$ (at least for $s\ne 0$).

Comment: Under the question that you linked, there was a comment asking about a Schwartz function that didn't validate, and there was a clarification you need to integrate over the whole $\mathbb R^\times$, and consequently odd Schwartz functions aren't particularly useful since they integrate to zero. I'm wondering if your Schwartz function is applicable since its only Schwartz on $x \in (0,1)$.

Comment: @StevenClark Yes this is the crux of the matter - I hope someone knows how to resolve this

Comment: Perhaps the even function $$f_r(x)=e^{\frac{r}{\log(|x|)}},\quad-1<x<1$$ where $$\int_{-1}^1 e^{\frac{r}{\log (| x| )}}\, |x|^{s-1} \, dx=4\, \sqrt{\frac{r}{s}}\, K_1\left(2\, \sqrt{r s}\right),\quad r>0\land\Re(s)>0$$ would be a better choice. You still wouldn't be able to integrate over the whole $\mathbb R^\times$, but at least you could account for the symmetric contribution in the left-half plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the even function

$$f_r(x)=e^{\frac{r}{\log(|x|)}},\quad-1<x<1\tag{1}$$

where

$$\Gamma\left[f_r,s\right]=\int\limits_{-1}^1 f_r(x)\, |x|^{s-1}\, dx=2 \int\limits_0^1 f_r(x)\, x^{s-1}\, dx=4\, \sqrt{\frac{r}{s}}\, K_1\left(2\, \sqrt{r s}\right),\quad r>0\land\Re(s)>0\tag{2}.$$

---

Most of the remainder of this answer will focus on the case

$$f_1(x)=e^{\frac{1}{\log(|x|)}},\quad-1<x<1\tag{3}$$

---

Since $f_1(x)$ is an even function of $x$ it can be approximated on the interval $x\in(-1,1)$ by the 2-periodic Fourier cosine series

$$f_1(x)\approx \frac{a_0}{2}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^K a_k\, \cos(\pi k x)\tag{4}$$

where

$$a_k=\int\limits_{-1}^1 f_1(x)\, \cos(\pi k x)\, dx\tag{5}$$

---

I don't have a closed form for the Fourier series coefficient $a_k$ defined in formula (4) above, but these coefficients can be approximated using numeric integration and decrease in magnitude as the value of $k$ increases as illustrated in the following table.

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 k & a_k \\
 0 & 0.559464 \\
 1 & 0.342683 \\
 2 & 0.0618051 \\
 3 & 0.0188978 \\
 4 & 0.0256676 \\
 5 & 0.0115177 \\
 6 & 0.0113023 \\
 7 & 0.00845802 \\
 8 & 0.00675756 \\
 9 & 0.00606805 \\
 10 & 0.00487649 \\
 11 & 0.00449404 \\
 12 & 0.00381808 \\
 13 & 0.00349118 \\
 14 & 0.00310478 \\
 15 & 0.00282947 \\
 16 & 0.00258617 \\
 17 & 0.00236765 \\
 18 & 0.00219612 \\
 19 & 0.0020276 \\
 20 & 0.00189614 \\
\end{array}$$

---

Figure (1) below illustrates the Fourier series for $f_1(x)$ defined in formula (4) above in orange overlaid on $f_1(x)$ defined in formula (3) above in blue where the Fourier series is evaluated at $K=20$.

[image: Illustration of Fourier series for f_1(x) (orange) overlaid on f_1(x) (blue)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of Fourier series for $f_1(x)$ (orange) overlaid on $f_1(x)$ (blue)

---

The Fourier transform

$$\hat{f_1}(w)=\int\limits_{-1}^1 f_1(x)\, e^{-i 2 \pi w x}\tag{6}$$

of $f_1(x)$ can be approximated by the following term-wise Fourier transform

$$\hat{f_1}(w)\approx \frac{a_0}{2}\frac{\sin(2 \pi w)}{\pi w}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^K a_k\, \frac{2 k \sin(\pi k) \cos(2 \pi w)-4 w \cos(\pi k) \sin(2 \pi w)}{\pi k^2-4 \pi w^2}\tag{7}$$

of formula (4) above.

---

Figure (2) below illustrates the formula (7) series above for $\hat{f_1}(w)$ in orange overlaid on formula (6) for $\hat{f_1}(w)$ in blue where the formula (7) series is evaluated at $K=20$ and numeric integration is used to evaluate the Fourier transform in formula (6) above.

[image: Illustration of formula (7) series for \hat{f_1}(w) (orange) overlaid on \hat{f_1}(w) (blue)]

**Figure (2)**: Illustration of formula (7) series for $\hat{f_1}(w)$ (orange) overlaid on $\hat{f_1}(w)$ (blue)

---

The function

$$\Gamma\left[\hat{f_1},1-s\right]=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f_1}(w)\, |w|^{-s}\, dw=2 \int\limits_0^\infty \hat{f_1}(w)\, w^{-s}\, dw\tag{8}$$

can be approximated by the following term-wise Mellin transform

$$\Gamma\left[\hat{f_1},1-s\right]\approx \frac{a_0}{2} \left(-2^{s+1} \pi^{s-1} \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right) \Gamma(-s)\right)+\frac{1}{2} \pi^{s+\frac{1}{2}} \sec\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right) \sum\limits_{k=1}^K a_k\, \left(\pi k \sin (\pi  k) \, _1\tilde{F}_2\left(1;\frac{s+2}{2},\frac{s+3}{2};-\frac{1}{4} k^2 \pi ^2\right)+2 \cos (\pi  k) \, _1\tilde{F}_2\left(1;\frac{s+1}{2},\frac{s+2}{2};-\frac{1}{4} k^2 \pi ^2\right)\right)\tag{9}$$

of formula (7) above.

---

Figure (3) below illustrates $\Gamma\left[f_1,s\right]\, \zeta(s)$ in blue and $\Gamma\left[\hat{f_1},1-s\right]\, \zeta(1-s)$ in orange where formula (2) above is used to evalute $\Gamma\left[f_1,s\right]$ and formula (9) above evaluated at $K=20$ is used to approximate $\Gamma\left[\hat{f_1},1-s\right]$. Note $\Gamma\left[\hat{f_1},1-s\right]\, \zeta(1-s)$ (orange) seems to approximate $\Gamma\left[f_1,s\right]\, \zeta(s)$ (blue) for $s>0$ where the imaginary part of $\Gamma\left[f_1,s\right]$ has a branch.

[image: Illustration of Gamma[f_1,s] zeta(s) in blue and Gamma[\hat{f_1},1-s] zeta(1-s)$ in orange]

**Figure (3)**: Illustration of $\Gamma\left[f_1,s\right]\, \zeta(s)$ in blue and $\Gamma\left[\hat{f_1},1-s\right]\, \zeta(1-s)$ in orange

---

Figure (4) below illustrates $2^s\, \pi^{s-1}\, \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\, \Gamma(1-s)\, \Gamma\left[f_1,s\right]$ in blue and $\Gamma\left[\hat{f_1},1-s\right]$ in orange where formula (2) above is used to evaluate $\Gamma\left[f_1,s\right]$ and formula (9) above evaluated at $K=20$ is used to approximate $\Gamma\left[\hat{f_1},1-s\right]$. Note $\Gamma\left[\hat{f_1},1-s\right]$ (orange) seems to approximate $2^s\, \pi^{s-1}\, \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\, \Gamma(1-s)\,\Gamma\left[f_1,s\right]$ (blue) for $s>0$ where the imaginary part of $\Gamma\left[f_1,s\right]$ has a branch.

[image: Illustration of 2^s pi^(s-1) sin(pi s/2) Gamma(1-s) Gamma[f_1,s] in blue and Gamma[\hat{f_1},1-s] in orange]

**Figure (4)**: Illustration of $2^s\, \pi^{s-1}\, \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\, \Gamma(1-s)\, \Gamma\left[f_1,s\right]$ in blue and $\Gamma\left[\hat{f_1},1-s\right]$ in orange

---

In summary, for $f_r(x)$ defined in formula (1) above, I believe the closed form for $\Gamma\left[\hat{f_r},1-s\right]$ is

$$\Gamma\left[\hat{f_r},1-s\right]=\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(1-s)}\, \Gamma\left[f_r,s\right]=2^s\, \pi^{s-1}\, \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\, \Gamma(1-s)\, \Gamma\left[f_r,s\right]\tag{10}$$

where $\Gamma\left[f_r,s\right]$ is defined in formula (2) above.